# Kafka spout error "Consumer is not subscribed to any topics or assigned any partitions "

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am using Storm version 1.1.0 and Kafka version 0.10.1.2.

I am creating Kafka-spout as follows:

```
public KafkaSpout<String, String> getKafkaSpout() {
    String _kafkaBrokers = (String) props.get("bootstrap.servers");
    String _topic = (String) props.get("kafka.topic.name");
    String groupId = (String) props.get("group.id");
    int maxMsgSize = (int) props.get("fetch.message.max.bytes");
    String keySerializer = (String) props.get("key.serializer");
    String valueSerializer = (String) props.get("value.serializer");

    List<String>topics = new ArrayList<String>(`enter code here`);
    topics.add(_topic);

    return new KafkaSpout<String, String (KafkaSpoutConfig.builder(_kafkaBrokers, topics)
            .setFirstPollOffsetStrategy(FirstPollOffsetStrategy.UNCOMMITTED_EARLIEST)
            .setMaxUncommittedOffsets(100)
            .setProp(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId)
            .setProp(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG,maxMsgSize)
            .setProp("key.serializer",keySerializer)
            .setProp("value.serializer",valueSerializer)
            .build())
}
```

I am getting below mentioned error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Consumer is not subscribed to any topics or assigned any partitions 
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:973) 
at org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpout.pollKafkaBroker(KafkaSpout.java:291) 
at org.apache.storm.kafka.spout.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:225) 
at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__9798$fn__9813$fn__9844.invoke(executor.clj:647) 
at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__555.invoke(util.clj:484) 
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

along with other dependencies I have below mentioned maven dependencies in project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-kafka-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.2.6.2.0-205</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.2.6.2.0-205</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that `List<String>topics = new ArrayList<String>("enter code here");` is your issue? You probably need to write in your topic name(s) in that list.

Your dependency versions are odd, AFAIK Storm hasn't released anything with those version strings.

I'm also wondering why you need both storm-kafka-client, which is for Kafka > 0.10 clusters, and storm-kafka, which is for older Kafka clusters (but still compatible with the latest Kafka at the moment I think).